# CSS 3D Box rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I am trying to create a div which would look as a box, and then it would automatically rotate to show different texts within it.

The effect in question is as shown in the 'RATATOUILLE', 'LASSITUDE', 'MURMUROUS', PALIMPSEST' & 'ASSEMBLAGE' buttons on the page: 
http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLinkEffects/

I did use the code from a previous project written by someone else (author unknown).

I have a cube div, with 4 panels in it, and first 2 panels marked initial panel and next panel

```
<div class="cube flip-to-bottom">
    <div class="initialpanel"><span>1st Panel</span></div>
    <div class="nextpanel"><span>2nd Panel</span></div>
    <div><span>3rd Panel</span></div>
    <div><span>4th Panel</span></div>
</div>
```

both styled

```
.initialpanel {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(25px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(25px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(25px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(25px);
    transform: translateZ(25px);
}

.nextpanel {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-25px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-25px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-25px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-25px);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-25px);
}
```

and finally a class which enables flip on the cube div

```
.flipNow {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(89deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(89deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(89deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(89deg);
    transform: rotateX(89deg);
}
```

Tying these two together is my javascript which would go through the cube's children div, renaming through each iteration to animate using CSS.

```
function startRotating(currentIndex) {
    current  = $(".cube >div.initialpanel");
    nextCurrent = current.next();
    next = $(".cube >div.nextpanel");
    nextNext = next.next();

    var flipNow = setTimeout(function(){
        $(".cube").addClass("flipNow");
    }, 2000);

    var stopFlip = setTimeout(function(){
        $(".cube").removeClass("flipNow");
        current.removeClass("initialpanel");
        next.addClass("initialpanel");
        next.removeClass("nextpanel");
        nextNext.addClass("nextpanel");
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        if(nextNext.length ===1){
            startRotating($("div.initialpanel"));
        }
    },4000);
}
```

This code is supposed to rotate panel 1 and show panel 2, and rotate panel 2 and show panel 3, and rotate panel 3 and show panel 4 and stop after panel 4 as there are no more panels.

The rotation and revelations occour as expected, but due to removing flipNow class and renaming children div classes, the flip reverts back to initial position and then rotates to its new position. This is a link where a working copy of my problem is being hosted: http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/m71osbLt/4/

any help would be appreciated which would help me to stop the double rotation on every panel reveal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your fiddle (quite heavily) to give you a general case for N sided figure (in my example it's 5): [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m71osbLt/7/). If you need further explanation, ask`.`

Comment: Hi Radu, thanks for the solution. I started out doing a Nsided animation, but got lost along the lines. From the code I can see that each div is already at -90deg initially, and when normal is added, it moves up to 0deg which is the animation to flip; and when top is added it further rotates by 90deg ?

I don't know how it works, but it does. Thanks for the answer, simple and yet brilliant!

Comment: @rand0m Yes, you understood well - there are 3 stages: -90,0,90 (except the initial layer, that has only two 0,90).
The thought behind this arrangement was that, i had no idea if you wanted to use it for a cube, or something resembling a stack with multiple layers, where you wanted to emulate a cube rotation. I hope it helped you.